# Construct the square root of Green's function

Tags: differential-equations, operator-theory, green-function

The boundary value problem

\begin{align}
&\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d}x } \left( p(x) \frac{\mathrm{d} y(x)}{\mathrm{d}x } \right) + q(x) y(x) = f(x), \quad a \leq x \leq b \nonumber\\
&y(a) = 0,\quad y(b) = 0
\end{align}

can be solved by Green’s function

\begin{align}
y(x) = \int_a^b G(x,\xi) f(\xi) \mathrm{d}\xi.
\end{align}

The Green’s function can be constructed from two independent solutions of the homogeneous problem $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ satisfying $y_1(a)=0$, $y_2(b)=0$ and $y_1(b)\neq 0$, $y_2(a) \neq 0$

\begin{align}
\label{eq:green}
G(x,\xi) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{y_1(\xi) y_2(x)}{p(\xi)W(\xi)}, & a \leq \xi \leq x, \\
\frac{y_1(x) y_2(\xi)}{p(\xi)W(\xi)}, & x \leq \xi \leq b.
\end{cases}
\end{align}

$W(x) = y_1(x)y'_2(x) - y_2(x) y'_1(x)$ is the Wronskian.
On the other hand, the Green’s function can be expressed in the form of an eigenfunction expansion.
Denote

\begin{align}
M = \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d}x } \left( p(x) \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d}x } \right) + q(x).
\end{align}

The Green’s function is

\begin{align}
G(x,\xi) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\phi_n(x) \phi_n(\xi)}{\lambda_{n}},
\end{align}

where $M \phi_n(x) = \lambda_n \phi_n(x)$.
Assume all the eigenvalues are positive $\lambda_n > 0$. Consider the square root of the Green’s function in the sense of

\begin{align}
H(x,\xi) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\phi_n(x) \phi_n(\xi)}{\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}}.
\end{align}

The question is that can $H(x,\xi)$ be expressed by $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ like the case of $G(x,\xi)$?

Comment: I don't think this is a realistic expectation. If you denote your Sturm-Liouville operator by $L$, then $G$ is the integral kernel of $L^{-1}$, which can be expressed in terms of $y_1$, $y_2$ because $L^{-1}f=y$ is essentially an ODE and you can apply variation of constants. Now $H$ is the kernel of $L^{-1/2}$, and no such interpretation is available.

Comment: Try a simple example like $\phi_n(x)=\sin{nx}$.